# count an array rows and the highest value an index in java

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Hegyek> lista = new ArrayList<Hegyek>();
    try{
        File fájl = new File("hegyekMo.txt");
        Scanner olvasó = new Scanner(fájl, "UTF-8");

        olvasó.nextLine();
        while(olvasó.hasNextLine()){
            String[] sor = olvasó.nextLine().split(";");
            Hegyek hegy = new Hegyek();
            hegy.név = sor[0];
            hegy.hely= sor[1];
            hegy.magassag = Integer.parseInt(sor[2]);
            lista.add(hegy);
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("File not exist!");
        System.exit(1);



    }
}
```

Hello, i am new here. How can I count the rows of "hegyekMo.txt" has, and Where is the sor[2] the highest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to know the count of rows in the file "hegyekMo.txt" you could just add an integer to you application (`int count = 0;`). This integer will be increased by one in the while loop (`count++;`). After the while loop has ended the integer count will give you the number of rows in the file.
- I am not sure if you just want to know the highest index but if this is what you want you will get it by using the final variable length (`sor.length`).

Hope I could help you, keep your work up!

Answer (score 0):

Need 2 auxiliary parameters, one for row count and one for max.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Hegyek> lista = new ArrayList<Hegyek>();
    try{
        File fájl = new File("hegyekMo.txt");
        Scanner olvasó = new Scanner(fájl, "UTF-8");

        olvasó.nextLine();

        int rowCount = 0;
        int maxVal =Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        while(olvasó.hasNextLine()){
            rowCount++;
            String[] sor = olvasó.nextLine().split(";");
            Hegyek hegy = new Hegyek();
            hegy.név = sor[0];
            hegy.hely= sor[1];
            
            hegy.magassag = Integer.parseInt(sor[2]);
            if(maxVal<magassag) maxVal = magassag;
            lista.add(hegy);
        }
        //output (rowCount and maxVal)
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("File not exist!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Note: Since you stored values in a `List`, you could just use `size()` method to get number of elements in the `List` which are also lines in file. Max could be obtain also form `List` using maybe `Lambda`.